# sRGB to NSColor

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nscolor

I am trying to draw an inner shadow in an NSView. The shadow itself is not the problem, but the color setting is driving me nuts :/

```
#define ShadowBlurRadius 10.0
#define SRGB (CGFloat [4]){184.0, 184.0, 184.0, 1.0}

@implementation SWShadowedView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
[context saveGraphicsState];

[context setCompositingOperation:NSCompositePlusDarker];


NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(0, dirtyRect.size.height -ShadowBlurRadius, self.superview.frame.size.width, ShadowBlurRadius)];

[[NSColor whiteColor] setStroke];

NSShadow * shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];

NSColorSpace *colorSpace = [NSColorSpace sRGBColorSpace];

NSColor *color = [NSColor colorWithColorSpace:colorSpace components:SRGB count:4];

[shadow setShadowColor:color];

[shadow setShadowBlurRadius:ShadowBlurRadius];
[shadow set];

[path stroke];

[context restoreGraphicsState];

[super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}

@end
```

If I replace the shadow color with [NSColor redColor] it works but with the wrong color. This is where I got the sRGB from: [link](http://d.pr/htmm+)

The way to convert sRGB to NSColor is taken from another post from here but obviously it's not working.

best regards

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use **RGB** not **sRGB**:

You can create color with RGB like this:

```
float red = 182.0f/256.0f;
float green = 182.0f/256.0f;
float blue = 182.0f/256.0f;


NSColor *color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation for pushing your answer.

Comment: This is ***NOT*** the same thing as generating a color using sRGB values. This is generating a color using the current calibrated RGB color space, which is definitely not guaranteed to be sRGB. You will not get the correct color if you enter sRGB values.

Comment: @RobKeniger I suggest to use RGB instead of sRGB. I know the differences, but with RGB is much easear to get what color exactly you want than using sRGB.

Comment: No, it isn't. It might be simpler for the programmer, but that doesn't mean that the color you get will be correct. sRGB is a standard color space. If you go into Photoshop and set your document's color model to sRGB, then you can guarantee that a pixel that measures R184,G184,B184 with the eyedropper will look *exactly* the same in your app if you use the sRGB color space as I explained in my answer. If you take that sRGB value and use it with the `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace` then the color will *not* be the same. Try it and see.

Comment: I concur with Rob, this answer is very misleading and one should never advise the use of "RGB" instead of sRGB without making it perfectly clear what is meant by "RGB".

Answer (score 6):

Your code is almost completely correct, the only problem is that you're using numerical values from 0-255 in your array. All the `NSColor` creation methods use `CGFloat` values from 0-1.0.

All you need to do is define your `SRGB` array like so:

```
#define SRGB (CGFloat [4]){184.0/255.0, 184.0/255.0, 184.0/255.0, 1.0}
```

Your code will then work correctly. Please note that using the `colorWithCalibratedRed:green:blue:alpha:` method of `NSColor` will **not** give you the correct color from your sRGB values.

To get correct sRGB values, you must use the method in your original code, which specifically uses the sRGB color space to create the color. A category on `NSColor` that creates colors using 255-based sRGB values might look something like this:

```
@implementation NSColor (sRGB_Additions)
+ (NSColor *)colorWith255sRGBRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    CGFloat sRGBComponents[4] = {red / 255.0, green / 255.0, blue / 255.0, alpha};
    NSColorSpace *colorSpace = [NSColorSpace sRGBColorSpace];
    return [NSColor colorWithColorSpace:colorSpace components:sRGBComponents count:4];
}
@end
```

Then you could just do this:

```
NSColor* someColor = [NSColor colorWith255sRGBRed:184.0 green:184.0 blue:184.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Awesome. Lifted for my own purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest, most modern way of creating the color that you need:

```
NSColor *color = [NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:(184.0 / 255.5) green:(184.0 / 255.5) blue:(184.0 / 255.5) alpha:1.0];
```